# What are the dimensions of the largest cylinder that can fit inside a sphere?

Tags: calculus

What are the dimensions of the largest cylinder (in terms of volume) that can fit inside a sphere?

I know that this problem involves taking the derivative of the V(r) equation and finding the maximum value, but i am having trouble finding the equation. Can anybody help form the equation?

Comment: Similar:                                              http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245745/what-is-the-maximum-volume-of-a-cylinder-that-can-fit-in-a-sphere-of-a-constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r$ be the radius of the cylinder, $R$ be the radius of the sphere, and $h$ be half the height of the cylinder. If we look at the cross section of the sphere, it will look like this:

[image]

Then we see that $h^2 + r^2 = R^2 \Rightarrow h = \sqrt{R^2 - r^2}$.