# A right circular cylinder is inscribed in a sphere of radius a > 0. What is the height of the cylinder when its volume is maximal?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

A right circular cylinder is inscribed in a sphere of radius a > 0. What
is the height of the cylinder when its volume is maximal?

My attempt : i know that volume of cylinder = π(a^2)h

```
                             Surface area = πah + π(a^2)h = S

                                 S  = πah + π(a^2)h

   for Maximum , dV/dx = (1/2)(S- 6πa^2)= 0

                      S  = 6πa^2

                     S  = 6πa^2.

  i know that h = S -π(a^2)h/2πa

            i got     h = 2a is the required answer
```

Is my answer is correct or not,,PLiz verified my solution

Comment: For more complete answer: how do you know there is a maximum?  Derivative zero.... could be a local maximum, could be a local minimum, could be neither, so you have to check.  Tell us the range of values $h$ that you allow.

Comment: What is the radius of the cylinder when its height is $2h?$

Comment: when height is 2h it will become 2h=4a @ amd

Comment: See answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245745/what-is-the-maximum-volume-of-a-cylinder-that-can-fit-in-a-sphere-of-a-constant).

Comment: Thanks a LOt @Jens

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta$ be the angle from the center of the sphere to the tip of the cylinder. Then

$$
r=a\cos\theta\\
h=2a\sin\theta\\
V=\frac{\pi rh}{3}=\frac{2\pi a^3}{3}\cos^2\theta\sin\theta
$$

Setting $dV/d\theta=0$ to find the maximum value, we get

$$-2\cos\theta\sin^2\theta+\cos^3\theta=-2\tan^2\theta+1=0\\
\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 35.262^{\circ}
$$

Then $h$ and $r$ are given as above. If it's of interest, the surface are of the cylinder is given by (not including the top and bottom) is given by

$$S=2\pi r\sqrt{r^2+h^2}=2\pi a^2\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+2\sin^2\theta}=2\pi a^2\sqrt{1+\sin^2\theta}$$

Comment: thanks  @ Cye Waldman...but im  not getting,,,,that  h =(acosθ)/(2asinθ) that mean θ=π/4

Comment: @Jameslegolegoh Interesting. I wonder where we differ. Do you agree with my equation for $V$? I plotted $\cos^2\theta\sin\theta$ and find the maximum where I said it is. As for your solution, if $h=2a$, how does a cylinder fit within the sphere, which has a diameter of $2a$? What is $r$ in that case? I urge you to rethink this.